# Loop through elements and get value from a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table with rows like this:

```
<tr class="d-flex linkObj" style="display: flex !important;">
    <th class="col-4">
        <div class="document-icon">
            <i class="far fa-file-code"></i>
        </div>
        <span class="file_data">Tobier - WordPress Tutorials, SEO Tools und vieles mehr<br>
            <span class="analyse_url quelle">https://tobier.de</span>
        </span>
    </th>
    <th class="col-2">
        Bild: https://tobier.de/media/2018/06/logo-4.png
    </th>
    <th class="col-2">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle text-success"></i> follow
    </th>
    <th class="col-4">
        <div class="document-icon">
            <i class="far fa-file-code"></i>
        </div>
        <span class="file_data">https://tobier.de<br>
            <span class="analyse_url ziel">https://tobier.de</span>
        </span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

i am iterate through all rows and want check the `<span class="analyse_url ziel">` value.
so my iterate looks like this:

```
jQuery('.linkObj').each(function (i, obj) {
    //if span value == 'https://tobier.de' do this:
    obj.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
});
```

all my attempts to access the span from the object failed, can you help me get the content of the spans?

Comment: jQuery('.linkObj').find('.analyse_url.ziel').each(function(i,obj){  if($(obj).text()=='https://tobier.de'){ $(obj).css('display','none!important');}  });

Comment: @gijoe the `css()` method does not support the `important` flag. It's not needed for inline styling in any case

Comment: Yes you re right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `span` within the `tr`, you can use `find()` within your `each()`. Then you can perform the check on the `text()` of that element and call `hide()` on the `tr`, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.linkObj').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('span.analyse_url').text() == 'https://tobier.de') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Note that you can make this slightly more succinct by providing a boolean value to `toggle()`:

```
$('.linkObj span.analyse_url').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).find('span.analyse_url').text() != 'https://tobier.de');
});
```

Comment: ok, this gets the span element direct...but i want first get the linkObj and when the span inside is the searched value, than hide the complete row

Comment: Ah I see. I've edited the answer for you in that case

Comment: ok, but hide() not working because the tr has display: flex !important....and on the "this" i cant set style.setProperty()

Comment: i will clean up this this !important stuff xD

Comment: That's a good idea as you shouldn't really use `! important` unless there is literally no alternative. Try using selector precedence instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.linkObj .analyse_url.ziel').each(function (i, obj){
    //if span value == 'https://tobier.de' do this:
    if(obj && (obj.innerHTML == 'https://tobier.de')){
        obj.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very important that you put the tag TR inside a TABLE otherwise it does not work. And that's the code.

```
$('.linkObj span.analyse_url').each(function(i, element) {
        var obj = $(element);
    if (obj.text() == "https://tobier.de") {
        obj.hide(); // hide the span
      obj.closest(".linkObj").hide(); // hide the entire row
     }
});
```